# Open the folder as another user in Debian

Tags: debian, nfs

I have logged to my debian as root using ssh. Than I have mounted some foler from my NAS using `mount -t nfs 192.168.1.222:/nfs /media/nfs`. Now I can access all subfolders. Exept `/media/nfs/somefolder`, bacause this folder available only for **admin**, not **root** (permissions was configured using NAS web GUI).

How can I open this folder using **admin** credentials? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to the admin user. Thought root should have access to anything. If it’s the remote end that is misbehaving, you’ll have to sort out acceptable permissions there first.

```
# su admin
$ cd /folder
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended, but you are using it in private network you can use **no_root_squash** in NFS config(/etc/export), It allows root users on client computers to have root access on the server.

```
/Directory/To/Share client_IP/Range(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```